# PLSQL - order by string with REGEX

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to sort the result set of a query where the row is VARCHAR2.
I've tried using just:

```
ORDER BY
UPPER(SERVER_NAME) ASC
```

But I get inconstant results, for example:

```
120157
777555
AKO
a20064
Elilikes
kagan
1200165_DAVID
```

As you can see, 1200165_DAVID appears last, in addition, I tried using a regular expression like so:

```
ORDER BY
(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(SERVER_NAME), '^[0-9]+$') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)  ASC,
UPPER(SERVER_NAME) ASC
```

But I get the same results, I would like to get the following ordring is possible:

```
120157
1200165_DAVID
777555
a20064
AKO
Elilikes
kagan
```

Please advise.

Comment: Your `SERVER_NAME` column mixes numbers with text.  Can you show us the exact ordering you would expect from the output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I updated the question with the order example.

Comment: So are the only four patterns text/numbers, numbers/text, text, or numbers, with possibly an underscore thrown in there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes, these are the patterns. I don't want to use a consuming operation as I don't really want to slow down the application.

Comment: You have unexpected characters in your strings.  In your case, it wouldn't be a space, tab, or newline, because those would appear first.

Comment: Seeing your entire query, to see what else may be wrong, could be helpful.

Comment: What does your question have to do with PLSQL (in your title)? Are you doing anything in a procedure, or is PLSQL just misleading?

Comment: @mathguy, the query is part of a procedure, I'm working on Oracle so I also did not want to mislead with the possibility of a different DB.

Comment: OK, perfect - that makes sense. Now - how can we be sure the order is wrong because of something Oracle does with the ORDER BY, and not anything else in your procedure? Is the whole procedure too long to post here?

Answer (score 1):

Three things.

**First**: Why do you want `1200165_DAVID` to appear AFTER `120157`? It should appear before it, if you order alphabetically.

**Second**: Running your query on your test data, I get the correct result. So I am inclined to believe either your query is different from what you reported, or there is some other error somewhere.

**Third**: You may have who-knows-what characters in your data. Selecting `str` and `dump(str)` side by side (or whatever the name of your expression; I like to use `str` in my test data) to see what characters are in each string. Look especially at those that seem to be sorted "out of order".

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select '120157'        from dual union all
       select '777555'        from dual union all
       select 'AKO'           from dual union all
       select 'a20064'        from dual union all
       select 'Elilikes'      from dual union all
       select 'kagan'         from dual union all
       select '1200165_DAVID' from dual
     )
select str from inputs
order by upper(str);

STR
-------------
1200165_DAVID
120157
777555
a20064
AKO
Elilikes
kagan

7 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Your data would appear to not be all characters that you recognize.  In particular, the first character is suspicious.

I would suggest that you run a query like this:

```
select ASCII(SUBSTR(server_name, 1, 1)) as first_char-ascii,
       '|' || SUBSTR(server_name, 1, 1) || '|' as first_char,
       COUNT(*), min(server_name), max(server_name)
from t
group by SUBSTR(server_name, 1, 1)
order by count(*) asc;
```

Then you will see what characters are actually at the beginning of the string.  My guess is you will find at least one interesting character.  You will then need to modify the data (or the query) to handle that.

Comment: Oracle has the `DUMP()` function to show exactly what characters are in a string. (Or in a value of any data type for that matter.)